# how to dismiss popup panel by dragging up ,down, right and left also it contains listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, drag

I have added fragment in frame layout which may contains list view and I want to dismiss it dragging on any side. Simply it is easy but with list view touch event not working properly.
[image]
[image]